# Opening wifi setting in IOS7

Tags: ios7, wifi, setting

I'm testing a feature

that when I can't get wifi connection

I will show a alert view and a button to go to system wifi setting

I know that in IOS6.0 this can't be done

but today I downloaded google map with my Iphone 5(IOS 7.0.6)

If I didn't have Wifi and 3g it will pop out a view

and if I press setting I can go to wifi setting

So I think this feature can be done in IOS 7
Can anyone tell me how to do this??

And Sorry about my poor English!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, the dialog you are seeing is  system dialog saying that if you turn on WiFi you will get a better location fix. As a developer you have no control over these dialogs.

Comment: Yes but it is a system dialog, just turn of you WiFi start you app and start the location manager location updates.

Comment: So I can open wifi by this system dialog?
cause I saw the switch in system's wifi setting.

Comment: No, as I wrote in my answer:  As a developer you have no control over these dialogs.

Comment: I think u try this by using a IOS7.0.6 iphone you will know what I mean. Close wifi and open google map.

Comment: @facebook-1618086794 as I mentioned it is not the Google Maps app that is displaying this dialog but iOS. As soon as you start monitoring the user location and your WiFi is turned off iOS will display this dialog. It has nothing to do with the app.

Comment: oh I know what u mean now.
So if I monitor user location and I can get this dialog.